# Neo4j - unable to get routing for database neo4j - unavailable after system upgrade

Tags: neo4j

I have been running a neo4j database for a while without problem.

Yesterday our server OS was update from centos-8 to centos-stream, and since this upgrade our neo4j database does not start anymore.

The service is listed as running but on every query it says: Unable to get a routing table for database 'neo4j' because this database is unavailable.

I cannot log in to the cypher shell because it shuts down with the same error.

I'm not sure what I can do here, I would like to not reset the database as we need the information in there.

The versions I'm running are as follows:
neo4j-4.3.6-1.noarch
neo4j-java11-adapter-1-1.noarch

Comment: Any error messages in the logs ?

Comment: @aldrin No, neo4j service started as normal but the database 'Neo4j' is unavailable for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, so I checked the logs and found the below error in the logs.

> Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
> /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/neo4j/neostore

The fix for the above issue is to change the ownership of noe4j databases folders and files.

```
cd /var/lib/neo4j/data
sudo chown -R neo4j:neo4j databases/
sudo chown -R neo4j:neo4j transactions/
```

Restart the neo4j service

```
sudo systemctl restart neo4j.service
```

Comment: This totally saved me. I have a NEO4J cluster running in Amazon on EC2. I connected via root and did a backup and needed to do exactly this to get the database out of the "Quarantined" state. Not sure why someone marked this as not the answer. I think I need to write up my experience and list this thank you @saji